# rEFInd - normal OSX not showing, just Recovery HD

Tags: macos, dual-boot, efi

I just installed rEFInd (to dualboot ubuntu) and all is working well so far, with a small exception: In the boot interface the normal OSX (Yosemite) is not there, it´s just showing the Recovery HD. That does not seem to be right. Any idea how to fix this?
(FileVault is not activated)

Comment: If it says something like **Boot OS X    from Recovery HD**, that is normal if you have FileVault enabled

Comment: yes, I read about that - but I haven´t enabled FileVault. Also I had installed rEFInd earlier, and there were two boot options for OSX: normal & recovery.

Comment: Perhaps editing refind.conf might help. You will have to mount EFI though. Open Terminal and type `diskutil list` You will see tables. Chose the one with HD in it (my case is /dev/disk0). Look for EFI somewhere near the HD tag and take note of its identifier on the right (mine is disk0s1). Next mount it with `diskutil mount disk0s1`. Now you can access it in `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/refind/refind.conf`

Comment: do you have any suggestions on what to edit? Out of curiosity I tried the fix from http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/yosemite.html (which should actually show the Recovery HD, but it didn´t change a thing). Maybe one more question - could it cause problems to boot from the Recovery HD?

Comment: And is the Recovery HD message an issue? How does it affect your normal "activity" on your device?

Comment: I haven´t spotted any differences so far. I was mostly wondering why the normal boot option is not showing up anymore (like in my previous reFINd install). It also seems strange that I have to boot from the Recovery HD - but as it seems to be normal when your using FileVault, there shouldn´t be a problem with it, I guess.